# How to perform mathematical operations using mean and standard deviation.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, standard-deviation, means

It's given that a particular parameter, say base-time $T_b$ follows a lognormal distribution with the mean of $10$ years and the standard deviation of $5$ years. Now, how do I estimate the value for another parameter `target-para $X$ which depends on 'base-time' as per the following equation:

$$X = K_1 + K_2(t - T_b)$$

where, $X$ is the parameter which is to be estimated, $K_1$ and $K_2$ are two constants, $t$ is the time in years, and $T_b$ is 'base-time'.

Comment: Does X = K1 + K2. (t - Tb) mean  "$X=K_1+K_2(t-T_b)$" ?

Comment: I've edited  your question for you. See: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Checked it. Thanks a lot. Looks much better now.

Comment: A quite trivial estimate is the expectation: $E[X]=K_1+K_2(t-E[T_b])$. Or  $$E[X]=K_1+K_2(t-10).$$ Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @zoli Maybe. What about the standard deviation for $X$ for the different values of $t$?

Comment: Whaddeya meeen "maybe"?

Comment: @zoli I mean yeah, expected value for $X$ seems alright, but what about its standard deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation is

$$E[X]=K_1+K_2(t-10).$$

The variance is
$$\sigma_X^2=E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[\{K_1+K_2(t-10)-(K_1+K_2(t-T_b)\}^2]=$$$$=K_2^2E[(10-T_b)^2]=25K_2^2.$$

So, the standard deviation

$$\sigma_X=5K_2.$$

Comment: Thanks, that helped. If you could also help me with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359124/finding-the-distribution-of-a-dependent-function-given-the-mean-and-coefficient, it would be great.