# Finding the distribution of a dependent function given the mean and coefficient of variation (COV) of the independent parameters.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

It is given that $A$ is log-normally distributed with a mean of 0.19 and coefficient of variation of 0.10, and $B$ is log-normally distributed with a mean 0.040 and COV equal to 0.10. Assume that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

How do I find the distribution, mean and coefficient of variance of $X$ if these parameters are related by the following equation:

$$X = {erf}^{-1} \left({\frac A B}\right)$$

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are not independent then we cannot handle this problem.

Comment: Yes, $A$ and $B$ are independent. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Next problem: the domain of $\operatorname {erf}^{-1}$ is $[-1,1]$. The range of $A/B$ is $[0,+\infty)$. How do you imagine $\operatorname {erf}^{-1}(A/B)$ ?